# TCPDUMP Network IPv6 Packets

Tags: networking, ipv6, wireshark, tcpdump

I am new to tcpdump tool and I am working in the analysis of network packets, I have analysed the IPv4 Ip packtes generated in case of wifi. But Now I am running my android phone in sim's 3g network which is generated the IPv6 packets ,completely different form IPv4 format. I am confused about the IPv6 packets structure,

Again, I have gone through the IPv6 header format, and my phone's packets given below, These two format does not match. I am totally confused about IPv6 header.

My mobiles's local ip is 100.87.163.16 ,my question is how to detect the received packets and sending packets. Also I want to find out the header length , payload length, source and destination ip address in IPv4 format. I am looking for your valuable suggestions.

Thanks.

```
10:59:06.365651 00:00:32:06:af:56 (oui Unknown) > 45:00:00:a8:35:49 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0xd83a), length 168:

0x0000:  c40e 6457 a310 01bb e6c0 f6b1 b5ed ec6b  �.dW�..������k
0x0010:  23f8 8018 015e dfc7 0000 0101 080a 17c2  #�...^��.......�
0x0020:  6af1 0014 f0c3 1703 0300 6f00 0000 0000  j�..��....o.....
0x0030:  0000 0208 7db4 d0c1 846d ca75 323c e6cb  ....}���.m�u2<��
0x0040:  1636 be16 942f 51ea 1caf 1c09 c085 3dbc  .6�../Q�.�..�.=�
0x0050:  7642                                     vB
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an IPv6 packet. How are you capturing it?  Also, 100.87.163.16 is an IPv4 address, not IPv6. Your IPv6 address would be more relevant to the question.

Comment: this ip 100.87.163.16 of my mobile. The packtes I am capturing by tcpdump command such as "tcpdump -X" .

Comment: can you elaborate where is the ip's ,header length and payload length in this packest

Comment: What makes you think you are using IPv6, or at least capturing IPv6 traffic?  The IP you've mentioned is an IPv4 address, not an IPv6 address.  You can't generate IPv6 traffic from that address.  The packet you're showing doesn't look like an IPv6 packet... I really don't think your capturing any IPv6 traffic.

Comment: I have used the shark reader app in android and try to view this packets. this app is indicating this packet as raw packet, after that nothing is showing.

Comment: According to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39317/10135) that app is only able to capture WiFi traffic, not your 3G network traffic.

Comment: @heavyd thank you  for giving me such usable information

Comment: @heavyd You are absolutely right, this does not look like an IPv6 packet. No matter how hard I try, I cannot find anything inside that packet, which could be interpreted as an IPv6 packet. There are only four places in which the number 6 exists at an alignment that could possibly be the version number field, and none of them give any valid result when interpreted as an IPv6 header.